# Is it possible to script opening terminal with 3 tabs?

Tags: macos, terminal

When I am testing this service, it requires 3-5 separate terminal windows to be open.

Would it be possible to somehow create a script that would open up 3 tabs in terminal, each pointing to a different folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following script: https://gist.github.com/2492064

Similar ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589114/opening-a-new-terminal-tab-in-osxsnow-leopard-with-the-opening-terminal-window